# Cant get to BIOS menu pages (aptio setup utility)

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, live-usb, bios

I have been trying to boot a USB pen with the gparted live, but it seems it is not detected. Most solutions that I found require me to access the BIOS setup where I should change the boot priorities and such, but the problem is that I can't get to the BIOS menu. The F2 tile gets me to "InsydeH20 Setup Utility" but it has only one page of information. The F12 gets me to "Boot Manager" where I can choose what device to boot from (but it only shows one, the HDD Device). How can i access the usually called "Aptio Setup Utility" (BIOS menu)?

PS: If there's a better place to post this question, please say where

PS: I have tested the USB stick and plug and they are working properly

PS: The first picture is the bios page I'm looking for

["Bios page that I'm looking for (image)"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnZOc.jpg)

["InsydeH20 Setup Utility (image)"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6nim.jpg)

["Boot Manager (image)"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vz9IE.jpg)

Comment: This is not related to Ubuntu at all. But you can select a USB bootable device. Did you try it?

Comment: Where can I selected it?

Comment: Also, do you know a better place to post this question?

Comment: Your second screenshot. Bootable device. Select USB.

Comment: I've tried selecting it but that's like a folder and it's empty